# Rotating an image with buttons on ios

Tags: ios, rotation

I'm trying to find a way to implement something similar to the wheel of fortune but that every traiangle is a button and each button will take the user to another screen. What do you think is the best way doing so?

I want to write my own code but as an example i've found this: http://www.walnutlabs.com/blog/?p=9

Which is great as for the wheel and the momentum but my problem is with the buttons.
How do i make them a triangle and how do i make them spin with the rest of the image? regular subviews will work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That really depends on your specific needs. It's certainly possible to achieve the visual look of your wheel by using subviews for buttons, but you cant make them responsive in a triangle shaped area.

If that's unacceptable I would suggest to create a UIView subclass for your wheel. In it's `drawRect:` method you do custom drawing to draw the wheel. Then you use the `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, `touchesMoved:withEvent:`, `touchesEnded:withEvent:` (maybe touchesEnded does suffice) methods to track which `button` (i.e. area in your view) the user touched and call the appropriate method.

Note:
It might be useful to add a delegate property to the custom view and a protocol to handle the actions in response to the touches somewhere else.

Comment: Interesting stuff, I'll check out all the above. What if i don't mind compromising on rectangle buttons, subviews for buttons would be the way to go? (I still want the buttons to spin with the wheel)

Comment: If the buttons are subviews of the 'wheelView' and you rotate the wheelView all subviews including the buttons will rotate with it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't entirely applicable but I think the project and comments would be useful:
[how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control-with-uikit](http://www.raywenderlich.com/9864/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control-with-uikit)